# Recovering AppleID using my rescue email address

Tags: apple-id

My iPhone got stolen and I don't have my AppleID. It was previously set by the vendor who sold me the iPhone. AFAIK, I only have my Gmail set as my rescue email address for the AppleID. Is there anyway to recover the ID so that I can recover my backups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at https://iforgot.apple.com and follow the instructions. If you don't know the Apple ID address used, choose ‘look it up’ and enter your name and email address.

Comment: I added my Gmail but it is not recognized. Does it require my Apple email address?

Comment: @user I'm not sure what you mean by ‘added’? The first box asks for the Apple ID address, if you don't know it click the ‘look it up’ link and fill out the information.

Comment: I just tried Look It Up, I entered my details but it does not recognize it.

Comment: @user Then you're out of luck I'm afraid as far as I know